# Creating new column based on minimum value on another column - R

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4)),
                 "Year" = c(2020,2019,2018,2017,
                            2020,2019,2018,2017),
                 "value" = c(30,20,0,0,
                             70,50,30,0))


> df
  id Year value
1  a 2020    30
2  a 2019    20
3  a 2018     0
4  a 2017     0
5  b 2020    70
6  b 2019    50
7  b 2018    30
8  b 2017     0
```

What I want to do is create a new column which has the same values as the `value` column, except wherever there is a `0` value it looks at the closest year with a non-zero value and applies that value to all `0` rows by each `id`. So the output should be:

```
> df
  id Year value newoutput
1  a 2020    30        30
2  a 2019    20        20
3  a 2018     0        20
4  a 2017     0        20
5  b 2020    70        70
6  b 2019    50        50
7  b 2018    30        30
8  b 2017     0        30
```

So for `id` `a` we see that years `2018, 2017` both have `0` values so need to be amended. The next year which has a non zero value is `2019`, so we take the value in that year which is `20` and apply it to both `2018, 2017`. Similar for `id` `b`.

Any ideas on how to do this using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr` and `cummax`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(newoutput = value + cummax((value == 0) * lag(value, default = T))) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   id     Year value newoutput
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 a      2020    30        30
#> 2 a      2019    20        20
#> 3 a      2018     0        20
#> 4 a      2017     0        20
#> 5 b      2020    70        70
#> 6 b      2019    50        50
#> 7 b      2018    30        30
#> 8 b      2017     0        30
```